# Alacritty: YAML config is deprecated, please migrate to TOML using `alacritty migrate`

Tags: terminal, arch-linux, migration, yaml, alacritty

Everytime I start alacritty I get the following error messages:

```
[0.000620404s] [WARN ] [alacritty] YAML config "/home/l540/.config/bspwm/alacritty/alacritty.yml" is deprecated, please migrate to TOML using `alacritty migrate`
[0.006481891s] [WARN ] [alacritty] YAML config "/home/l540/.config/alacritty/colors.yml" is deprecated, please migrate to TOML using `alacritty migrate`
[0.006952071s] [WARN ] [alacritty] YAML config "/home/l540/.config/alacritty/fonts.yml" is deprecated, please migrate to TOML using `alacritty migrate`
[0.009615369s] [WARN ] [alacritty_config_derive] Unused config key: history
[0.009631048s] [WARN ] [alacritty_config_derive] Unused config key: multiplier
```

I already ran 'alacritty migrate'. When I run it again, I get the following output:

```
Configuration file migration failed:
    "/home/l540/.config/alacritty/alacritty.toml": already in TOML format
```

Both ~/.config/bspwm/alacritty/ and ~/.config/alacritty/ have both TOML and YAML files in them.

How can I get rid of the error messages?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.yml` files (back them up first!)?

Comment: Yes, then the config is gone all together.

```[0.000010135s] [ERROR] [alacritty_config_derive] Unable to load config "/home/l540/.config/bspwm/alacritty/alacritty.yml": Unable to locate config file```

Answer (score 0):

To address the warnings and update your Alacritty configuration from YAML to TOML format, you can follow these steps:

1. Run alacritty migrate to convert your existing YAML configuration to TOML format.
2. Update the converted TOML configuration to fix any warnings or errors.